# How to embed multimedia HTML/JavaScript application into C++ code

Tags: javascript, c++, html, websocket, qtwebkit

I have source code of a JavaScript/HTML5 application, which runs on client-side and does the transferring/receiving of audio and video data streams to/from server.

My task is to create a C++ application, which completely embeds the functionality of the afore-said JavaScript/HTML5 application.

Basically, what I need is an UI-window, which embeds JS/HTML5 code, where the code will take care of the real application logic.

Which framework are suitable for this task? Qt comes to my mind but I can't seem to figure out whether the newly released and future versions of it would support HTML5 + video/audio/websockets as the QtWebKit module has been marked as deprecated.

Comment: It sounds like you want a full browser engine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine Any reason for not setting up a webserver and viewing the site in the browser?

Comment: @deviantfan Trying out this one:  https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef (will write later about the results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that Chromium Embedded Framework (aka CEF) completely solved my problem and is suitable for this type of tasks.